# How to remove cropping option when uploading an image in iOS/ swift

Tags: ios, swift

This is the image with cropping option.

[image]

I want to remove this cropping option and want to upload the full length image. Is it possible using iOS imagepicker?

When I am going to upload an image from photo gallery,it shows the cropping option. I don't want the crop option. I want to upload the full image without cropping it.How to remove that cropping option? Is it possible? Please help.
I have used the following code but it's not working:

```
 @IBAction func clickImageUpload(_ sender: Any)
{

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose an Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choose from Gallery", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

        self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
        self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        self.imagePickerController.delegate = self

        self.present(self.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take a Photo", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
            self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            self.imagePickerController.delegate = self

            self.present(self.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            print("No camera")
        }


    }))



    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {


    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage

        imgvwProfile.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imgvwProfile.image = image.squareMe()

    //imgvwProfile.image = image
    self.imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgvwProfile.image!, 1.0)!
    print(imageData)
   print(info)
    //obtaining saving path
    if let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] {

    if ((assetPath as! NSURL).absoluteString?.hasSuffix("JPG"))! {
        print("JPG")
        extensionType = "jpg"
    }
    else if ((assetPath as! NSURL).absoluteString?.hasSuffix("PNG"))! {
        print("PNG")
         extensionType = "png"
    }
    else if ((assetPath as! NSURL).absoluteString?.hasSuffix("GIF"))! {
        print("GIF")
         extensionType = "gif"
    }
    else {
        print("Unknown")
         //extensionType = "Unknown"
    }
    }

    if extensionType.count == 0 {
        extensionType = "jpg"
    }

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    print("IMAGE= \(documentsPath)")
    let imagePath = documentsPath?.appendingPathComponent("image.png")
    self.idProofDic["data"] = self.imageData as! Data
    self.idProofDic["mimeType"] = "image/\(extensionType)"
    self.idProofDic["extension"] = ".\(extensionType)"

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the functionality of UIImagePickerController? If so, it has nothing to do with uploading an image. Please [edit] your question to be clearer about what you are doing and what the problem actually is.

Comment: Can you post some image for more clear about question?

Comment: I have added the image. Please have a look. @rmaddy n  shahnilay86

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?  The image you have shown doesn't look like a standard UIImagePicker

Comment: @Paulw11 here is my code

Comment: What is the `squareMe` function?  Is that applying the crop?

Comment: I was trying  to increase the square ratio height. But its not working. @Paulw11 . Can you tell me that how to remove that cropping. Is it possible?

Comment: Remove the call to the `squareMe` function entirely?

Comment: removed already.but not able to remove the cropping @Paulw11

Comment: The image you have shown looks like there are additional translucent views in your scene - You aren't showing the standard image picker.  Whatever is happening it is your code or your view that is doing it.

Comment: Finally I resolved the issue. Thnx for ur support @Paulw11 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default controls to disable image cropping.

```
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
```

Comment: And also you have to add the following line of code:        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage